# What does --url -- mean in the windows registry command folder?

Tags: windows, registry

In the registry for discord Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Discord\shell\open\command, the value is `"Path\to\discord\Discord.exe" --url -- "%1"`. In the official microsoft documentation, it says that `"C:\path\to\discord\Discord.exe" "%1"` is valid, so I'm wondering what the `--url --` is for. Also this isn't only for discord, lots of other programs as well use other things like `--protocol-launcher` etc before the `"%1"`.

Comment: It is a command line argument what it means depends on the application.

Comment: oh thank you so much @Zoredache!